# How to run program constantly on web?

Tags: processing

I am beginger in programming. I'm now learning mostly Processing programming language. I would like to make visual program that will constantly evolve and run, even when nobody will watch it on the net. Is this possible in Processing(javascript mode?)?Or any better language for it? How? I would be happy for any information, or you can recommend me some book or topic. Thank you

Example: I would like to make AI and see how it is evolving in few days or even month, I can do it as desktop app on my computer and let this app run withou tun of cumputer, but that would be expensive, so I would like to put this program on on the net.

I have also some basic in HTML, Python and Javascript..

Roman, Czech republic

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

That's what servers are for. In the case of JavaScript, you would have to have a look at [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). So yes, it is possible, both in JavaScript and Python and other languages.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to use Processing language. For which keyword should I search to find more about this in references?

Comment: You can use Processing.js and put it online as it is on any webserver. You could probably even use GitHub pages or anywhere where you can upload static HTML+JavaScript, see "Putting it online" in Getting started: http://wiki.processing.org/w/JavaScript